# Rails: first_or_initialize(id: 1) NoMethodError: undefined method `empty?' for 0:Fixnum

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Running into an odd error while using first_or_initialize in my seeds

```
console> Model.where(association_id: 1).first
[]

console> Model.where(association_id: 1).first_or_initialize(...)

> Model Load (0.8ms)  SELECT  "models".* FROM "models" WHERE 
  "models"."association_id" = $1  ORDER BY "models"."id" 
  ASC LIMIT 1  [["association_id", 0]]
  NoMethodError: undefined method `empty?' for 0:Fixnum
```

---

How do I use first_or_initialize with id?

Comment: What do you mean with id? What is the contents of your `first_or_initialize`? I just tried this out and it's working fine.

Comment: @Ryan-NealMes The method doesn't work for me on this one particular model with or without content. It works on other models just fine, but throws the error when I use it on this model. I haven't a clue why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had defined a date column as a serialized column in my model, hence the error. Removed the bug and the method works fine.